# Ping Error Redirect Host New nexthop Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

In a internal network was working just fine I did format a laptop, and when I want to connect to another computer in the network from that laptop, I get an error

```
10.8.0.117 Laptop

10.8.0.116 Server

10.8.0.1 Server Router
```

```
ping -c 2 10.8.0.117
PING 10.8.0.117 (10.8.0.117) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.0.117: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=8.93 ms
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 117.0.8.10)
--- 10.8.0.117 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 1 received, +1 errors, 50% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.701/3.701/3.701/0.000 ms
```

If I connect to the server which it works as a router `10.8.0.1` and from there connects to `10.8.0.117`, it works. What could be the problem?

Comment: Just want to note that although "New nexthop:" is showing an inverted address, I think that's actually a bug in 'ping' itself and not something weird with OP's network specifically – I get the same whenever ICMP Redirects are involved.

Comment: It maybe ? Do not have to be with revers dns ?

Comment: Indeed the inverted IP address is just [a bug in ping](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/commit/e2e9a2d). It has been resolved recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did solve it ! I did set /32 on the mas insted of /24 on the set up seally of me but it will be nice some one explain why that happend well thank you for your time !